# What do I need to tunnel ICMP packets on a windows client?

Tags: networking, tunnel

I have a linux server running [PingTunnel](http://www.cs.uit.no/~daniels/PingTunnel/) to tunnel ICMP packets to regular TCP traffic.

What do I need to install on my windows client in order to get regular web browsing to work with this proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the instructions on the [ptunnel website](http://www.cs.uit.no/~daniels/PingTunnel/#using):

> The -p switch sets the address of the
>   host on which the proxy is running. A
>   quick test to see if the proxy will
>   work is simply to try pinging this
>   host - if you get replies, you should
>   be able to make the tunnel work.
>
> The -lp, -da and -dp switches set the
>   local listening port, destination
>   address and destination port. For
>   instance, to tunnel ssh connections
>   from the client machine via a proxy
>   running on proxy.pingtunnel.com to the
>   computer login.domain.com, the
>   following command line would be used:

```
sudo ./ptunnel -p proxy.pingtunnel.com -lp 8000 -da login.domain.com -dp 22
```

You will need to replace `proxy.pingtunnel.com` with your server that is running the proxy, `login.domain.com` is the website you would like to visit, and `22` should be `80`.  Then you should be able to enter http://localhost:8000 into your browser.

One down side of this is that you can only connect to one domain with each instance of ptunnel that is running, but still cool when you're in a pinch.